# how can I toggle the mousewheel behavior in Tilix?

Tags: command-line, bash, scrolling, mouse-wheel

I'm using Tilix as a terminal on Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal).

At the moment, I have two shells opened (two instances of bash) in a split window, both working, but:

- one has a scrollbar and responds to "mousewheel up/mousewheel down" by scrolling upwards/downwards,
- the other has no scrollbar and responds to the mousewheel by going up/down in my shell's command history.

```
$ tilix --version
Versions
    Tilix version: 1.9.1
    VTE version: 0.60
    GTK Version: 3.24.20

Tilix Special Features
    Notifications enabled=0
    Triggers enabled=0
    Badges enabled=1
```

**Question**

- What can I toggle, that would re-activate the "scroll mode" on the second shell window?
- Is it a Tilix toggle, or a bash toggle? (I would be surprised if it were the latter, but you never know)